# How to ask user for loop amount and then changing the question asked

Tags: python

So I was struggling with a question on how to ask for looped inputs. So when the user enters say 5 then the program will ask the user to enter the data 5 separate times. As I was looking through I found a program that solved that and I've tweaked it to suit my question and this is what I've gotten so far:

```py
def doSomething():   
    x = int(input ("Enter how many words?\n"))
    for count in range (x):
        word1 = input ("Enter word1:\n")

doSomething()
```

This part of the program solves my initial problem of asking the user for their input as many times as they have stated, but my problem is how do I change the program so that when the user enters for x = *5* the then the program will ask the user to input *Enter Word 1* and after the user enters the word the program asks for word 2 *Enter Word 2* and so on until its asks for the amount of words the user asked for. So to be direct how do I change *Enter Word 1* to *Enter Word 2* and *Enter Word 3* as the program loops the amount of times chosen by the user.

Comment: Look at string formatting in Python.

Comment: I can't vote I need more reputations, that's what it says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just get the number printed each time:

```py
def doSomething():
    x = int(input ("Enter how many words?\n"))
    for count in range (x):
        word1 = input (f"Enter word{count+1}:\n")
```

btw You need python 3.6 or higher for this.

Comment: The `f"string{variable}"` construct is new, but there are certainly mechanisms for interpolating a variable into a string going all the way back to Python 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formatting of strings or concatenation.
In the loop where you ask for input you can do any of the following

- `input("Enter word " + (count+1) + ":\n")` - Using string concatenation
- `input("Enter word {0}:\n".format(count+1))` - Using `.format()` strings
- `input(f"Enter word {count+1}:\n")` - Utilizing f-strings.

FYI, I'm adding 1 to each `count` because the `range` function starts from 0 and ends at `n-1`. Adding one will allow a range from 1 through n.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up concatenation. Along with that take a look at f strings. These are very efficient ways of concatination

```
for count in range(1,x+1):
    word1 = input (f"Enter word{count}:\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use an f string to achieve the required formatting.

```
def doSomething():
    x = int(input ("Enter how many words?\n"))
    for count in range (1, x+1):  # count starts from 1 and goes till x
        word = input (f"Enter word{count}:\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a list variable rather than five variables with separate names.

```py
word = []
for count in range (x):
       word[count] = input (f"Enter word[{count}]: ")
```

Now, `word` will contain someting like

```
['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
```

Notice that the index is zero-based, so the first string `'first'` is `word[0]` and `'second'` is `word[1]`. You could loop over `range(1, x+1)` but you probably should not; to mask the "computer" numbering from the user, you can display `count+1` to the user.

The design to require the user to decide ahead of time how much input to provide is unnecessary and rather cumbersome; a better design is to let them provide input into an ever-growing list until they separately indicate that they want to stop, by providing an empty input, or in a GUI by clicking a separate button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop like this. Also, make sure to check that the first number the user inputs is actually a number.

```py
while True:
    try:
        number_of_words = int(input('Enter the number of words: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('You must enter a number')

words = []
for word in range(number_of_words):
    words.append(input(f'Enter word {word + 1}: '))
print(words)
```